# SQL Server view, will it update itself, or does it require me to create a new one?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

A view is created, and certain users have direct access to the database using the same web application. If the base table is changed (data) will the view automatically reflect the changes/insert in data, or will it need to be created again and again?

Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2005, C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views are like windows, they just let you see what's in the table. They don't contain a copy of the table or anything like that.

If you change the definition of the table, like add or remove a column, you should rebuild the view. But if you are just doing insert/update/delete, then everything will just work.

Comment: "But if you are just doing insert/update/delete, then everything will just work." i am doing it to the base table not the view, even then 'every thing will be fine?'

Comment: Indexed views in SQL Server or materialized views in other RDBMS do in fact store a copy of the data - but even that copy is always kept up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Views recalculate themselves automatically. When this happens depends on the specific engine in use (read: I have no clue when for SQL Server 2005).

Answer (score 1):

In effect, a view is a just a pre-written select statement.

Every time you make a call to the database for a particular view, the select statement runs and the current dataset in the base table(s) is returned.

You won't see live changes in an application front-end if someone else makes a change to the data table but you will see any changes as soon as you make a new request for the view.

Comment: This is not entirely true for indexed views in SQL Server - they actually do store the data contained in the result of the view on disk. They're not really just a pre-written select statement...

Comment: "In effect" was shorthand for "here be dragons..." :D

In the context of the question an indexed view would not reflect any changes to other users until it was run again. As this needs to be done for a normal view anyway, the differentiation is probably unnecessary.

However, +1 for clarity and further explanation - something that gets forgotten about when answering a specific question.

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately only one can be marked as answer :-)